# Warning: Undefined array key 1

Tags: php, php-8.1, array-key

It only started giving me problems when i upgraded to php 8.1.

The issue is on the line `$time = $matches`

Although, this is a very generic question and probably has been answered quite a few time something similar. I looked through some of the other questions with a similar title but i'm still confused on what i need to do in my code particular.

```
   /**
         * Generates filtered time input from user to formatted time (YYYY-MM-DD)
         *
         * @param mixed $time
         * @return string
         */
        protected function filterTimeInput(mixed $time): string
        {
            $matches = [];
            preg_match('/(\d+-\d+-\d+)T(\d+:\d+)/', $time, $matches);
            $time = $matches[1] . " " . $matches[2];
            return strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', strtotime($time));
        }
```

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When provided `$time` does not match the pattern, the `$matches` will be an empty array. That will throw a "Undefined array key" error if you try access any index.

Comment: @AhmCho so what do i need to do to fix this? I need to assign something to $matches? I'm confused still on what needs to be done here.

Comment: The very first thing that comes in mind is just to check if `$matches` has any values (not empty) and then do your transformations. And if the the array is empty, your function may return the value as it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score -1):

To fix the error I would use `isset` builtin of PHP or *null coalesce* operator

```
$match_1 = $matches[1] ?? ""; # Null coalesce example
$match_2 = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : ""; # isset example
$time = $match_1 . " " . $match_2;
```